# How to bind gridView inside For Loop without Overwriting the previous binds?

Tags: binding, insert, view, grid, row

I'm binding a Grid View inside a for loop which executes more than once.Now when the loop ends the Data in grid view is the data binded at the last run of For loop i.e all Previous Binds in the For loop over overwritten.I dont want this .I want new rows to be Inserted at each run of the for Loop ..Plz help somebody. I dont get how to do this.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Plz write the complete code whoever knows it.I'll be highly gratefull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't databind in a loop.  Get your data sorted first, then assign it to the GridView's DataSource, then call Databind.

Comment: Yes that I can do but that will also take a long procedure.

Comment: I'm sure there must b a way to data bind inside a loop... but I donno dat

Comment: @CRice...Thanku for ur idea...I have sorted the data in a dynamic datatable and then binded it..Its working fyn nw.Although I had to hit and trial the datatable code many times..